# How to tell pip to create folders on installing my package

Tags: python, pip

I'm making python application for linux os. And I'm wondering
how can I make my package that will create config folders/files on
executing: `pip install my-package`.
On https://pip.pypa.io I didn't find if this is considered a bad practice,
since my app is part package/app, probably the best way would to make dpkg
package, but out of curiosity I want to know how can one achive this.

Answer (score 1):

Your typical `setup.py` file would be structured like so:

```
from setuptools import setup
import sys

setup(name = "package_name"
    .....
```

After the `setup` call you can use `os.mkdir` or anything else that you want to do.

Your final code would look something like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
import sys
import os

setup(name = "package_name"
    .....

 os.mkdir('test_path')
```

What `pip` typically does is run `python setup.py install`. When the setup file is run, the `os.mkdir` will get run and hence your directory will be created.

Comment: But what if setup.py is corupted? I don't want to mess users system before i'm not really 100% that package is installed on system properly.

Comment: Place the os.mkdir after the `setup`. In this case, if there are errors, it will not create the directory. Edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Hm... must to test this, I'm kinda suspicious obout this, but thanx for your input :)